# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, object, nullreferenceexception

I have the following code -

```
private static void convert()
    {
        string csv = File.ReadAllText("test.csv");
        XDocument doc = ConvertCsvToXML(csv, new[] { "," });
        doc.Save("update.xml");

        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("update.xml");
        XmlDocument testDoc = new XmlDocument();
        testDoc.Load(@"update.xml");

        XDocument turnip = XDocument.Load("update.xml");
        webservice.function[] test = new webservice.function[1];
        webservice.function CallWebService = new webservice.function();

        foreach(XElement el in turnip.Descendants("row"))
        {
                            test[0].com = System.Convert.ToInt32(el.Descendants("var").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "com").SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value);
            test[0].Centre = el.Descendants("var").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "Centre").SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value;
            test[0].CCentre = el.Descendants("var").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "CCentre").SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value;

            MessageBox.Show(test[0].person, "person");
            MessageBox.Show(System.Convert.ToString(test[0].actually), "Actually");
            MessageBox.Show(System.Convert.ToString(test[0].com), "Com");

            CallWebService.updateFeedStatus(test);
        }
```

It is coming up with the error of - NullReferenceException was unhandled, saying that the object reference not set to an instance of an object. The error occurs on the first line test[0].account.

How can I get past this?

Comment: post a stacktrace please, otherwise could be anywhere.

Comment: We're debugging in the dark - what line?

Comment: Why are you creating an array of size 1, instead of just an instance of the relevant class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: @John Saunders: This question was asked before that one, and is more specific

Comment: This is not a question, this is a "find my bug"

Comment: @Nellius: it should perhaps be edited to say, "help me find my bug". Under no circumstances should it have the current title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initializing an array does not initialize the objects in the array.  Try adding the second line below (assuming you want to use the default constructor):

```
webservice.singleSummary[] test = new webservice.singleSummary[1];
test[0] = new webservice.singleSummary();
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Put a debugger on the process.
2. Identify which line of code is generating the error.
   (Assuming Visual Studio)
3. Test the object references on that line one by one until you determine which one has the null reference.
4. Put in a null check before the line to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your xml has a namespace that you need to include in your xname for the desired elements, but as the other comments mention, there is little that can be done without full disclosure.